# Programatically create shipment (for selected items/qty on order) in magento

Tags: magento

I have an order that looks like this:
[image: dummy order]

I want to create a shipment for the following on this order (not for everything):

> **2 x VCF001**
>
> **1 x SBA364**

To achieve this, I found the following info on the shipment api: http://bit.ly/17rpuwj

Based on this documentation of the API, I came up with the following code. When I tried to execute it, I got the following error **Cannot create an empty shipment**:

```
$order_number = '300000002';
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_number);
$allocations = array(
    array('sku' => 'VCF001', 'allocated_qty' => 2),
    array('sku' => 'SBA364', 'allocated_qty' => 1)
);

function GetOrderItemId($order_items, $sku) {
    foreach ($order_items as $order_item) {
        if ($order_item->getSku() == $sku) {
            return $order_item->getItemId();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

function CreateShipment($order, $allocations)
{
    // Get Order Items
    $order_items = $order->getItemsCollection();

    // Parepare Item Qtys For Shipment
    $item_qtys = array();
    foreach ($allocations as $allocation) {
        $item_qtys[] = array(GetOrderItemId($order_items,
            $allocation['sku']) => $allocation['allocated_qty']);
    }

    // Anticipate Errors
    try
    {
        // Create Shipment
        $shipment = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api();
        $shipmentId = $shipment->create($order->getIncrementId(),
            $item_qtys, 'Pick #123 Sent to Warehouse');

        // Done
        echo 'Shipment Created - ID #'. $shipmentId;
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        print_r($e);
    }
}

CreateShipment($order, $allocations);
```

Any idea why this isn't working as intended? See the full exception log here : http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=GMN4WCAE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this instead :

```
    protected function _createShipment($order, $qtysForProducts)
    {
        $shipment = $order->prepareShipment($qtysForProducts);
        if ($shipment) {
            $shipment->register();

            $shipment->sendEmail(true)
            ->setEmailSent(true)
            ->save();

            $order->setIsInProcess(true);

            $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                ->addObject($shipment)
                ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                ->save();
        }

        return $shipment;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, at what point in this code do you specify the exact product and the qty I want to ship? This looks like it will create a shipment for everything on order.

Comment: Yep added qty, sorry : take a look at the `prepareShipment($qtys = array())` method in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` calling the `Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Order::prepareShipment($qtys = array())`

Comment: I tried that and still no luck. My amended code: http://pastebin.com/f2TJKF4N - getting the exact same error **Cannot create an empty shipment** - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=k9gnCaSx

Comment: Take a look a the functions I mentionned. You'll see that the $qty array you're using is wrong : you need an array like : $array[$productId] = $qty (entityId, not SKU, and single dimesnionnal)